# Python - curl request with requests, header not set correctly? (possible GitLab API issue)

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to use the Gitlab API to make an issue from Python.

The following curl request works (tested and confirmed):

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<my project id>/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug
```

My Python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2674887/issues", data={
        "title":issueform.instance.title,
        "description":issueform.instance.description
        },
                    headers={"PRIVATE_TOKEN":"<token>"})
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

I get: 401 Unauthorized

Am I doing something wrong in my POST request or is this an issue with GitLab rejecting doing it this way possibly?

The relevant part from the API:
http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#new-issue

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, ignore the `issueform.instance` stuff, they are just Strings (it is a Django project and I omitted the form stuff because it shouldn't be relevant)

Comment: CURL with `subprocess.Popen` and multiple params (`title=IssueABC&labels=bug`)wasn't working, probably something weird with the string encoding I guess... but dropping in `requests` is working great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change `PRIVATE_TOKEN` to `PRIVATE-TOKEN`

Comment: @Lomtrur well, we commit this kind of mistake

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it just a typo? could you try the below?

```
"PRIVATE-TOKEN"
```

instead of

```
"PRIVATE_TOKEN"
```